# Can you explain the underlying math in this question please? Regarding continuous expected values

Tags: expected-value

$X$ is a random variable. If I am given the $P(X<1)= 0$ and the $P(X>e) = 0$ and in the range $y$ in $[1,e]$ the $P(X<y)= \int_1^y \frac{1}{x} dx$. If $\mu$ is the expected value of $X$, what is the closest integer to $10 k$, where $k$ is given by $P(X- \mu>k)=0.05$.

My approach was to calculate the $\mu$ of $X$, which I think is the integral where $y = e$. What I get is $1/(e-1)$, which is $0.58$.

Does anyone know where to go from here? I thought to manipulate $P(X- \mu>k)=0.05$ to make it $1-P(X- \mu<k)=0.05$, because I have a given expression from here.

Thanks, and I apologize for the lack of clear formatting, this is my first time posting.

Comment: The mean of the distribution of $X$ cannot be lower than the lower limit of the support of the distribution. That is, the mean *cannot* be below $1$. You expect it to be between $1$ and $e$, and since the pdf is monotonic decreasing, somewhat closer to the $1$ end (and it turns out that this is the case; $E(X)$ is below the midpoint of the support).

Comment: The pdf is available in closed form, hence the quantiles are also available. And computing $\mu$ is even simpler.

Comment: @user296857 Perhaps you should show in more detail how you got the average you did

Comment: I took the integral from 1 to e which is 1, then divided by e-1.